# Term for the person to whom an employee directly reports

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

I am looking for a word or phrase to describe "the person to whom an employee directly reports".

I do not want to use "Supervisor" or "Manager" as these titles are both already used in the organization with distinct definitions; I want a hypernym which covers both of these titles.

I came up with "direct superior" as an option, as an opposite to the phrase "direct report", but I am not sure it is a common phrase. (A [google search for it](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=direct%20superior) seems to mainly return information about "direct superior hip replacements".)

Comment: You mean "direct report" to mean a person's immediate underling? I've not personally heard this term.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: I should think that 'line manager' is in the right ballpark, if not an exact antonym. You should check out 'direct superior' yourself and give your findings.

Comment: It's definitely in the ballpark, but I'm looking for something that doesn't include either "supervisor" or "manager".

Comment: How about “***boss***”

Comment: @Jim, too informal :) Also doesn't only refer to direct.

Comment: @user190361 - Ok, but formality wasn’t part of the question, and I only refer to my immediate supervisor as my boss.  The guy above that is my boss’s boss.

Comment: Why don't you want "manager", one of the most intuitively correct responses, to be part of the answer?

Comment: In some cases, department manager, or employees manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recognize "direct manager" the way I do "direct reports". I would say "**immediate superior**" or "**immediate manager**". "**Immediate supervisor**" works as well, but I would only use that for low-level employees that do not have direct reports themselves (I do not think it is correct to apply the term *supervisor* to, say, a senior vice president who has five direct reports and two thousand indirect reports).

I do not, however, speak from great personal experience in an American or English company. No real authoritative references, but some forums: [PROZ](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/English/human_resources/2083057-line_manager_vs_immediate_manager.html), [YAHOO](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081110142304AAhFzgM).

As an aside that may interest people, the French usual term is "N+1". Your "N+2" is logically your "boss's boss". People looking to translate that don't have any other ideas that I see: [WR](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/mon-n-1-est.424563/). French also has the noun "responsable", which unfortunately does not translate directly to English.